# Grid expand on data Clicked

Tags: extjs4

I have a Grid with say 10 rows and 5 columns. suppose the first column is "Name"
So the data would be some thing like

```
Name
abc
xyz
pqr
```

Now My query is, I want to Expand the Row on "abc" click, i.e. on "Name" columns data click. 
And wanted to show the data of the other columns from the same row.
[image]

I have attached the image , Hope this will clear my requirement.

In the image it is shown that, the RowExpander, we can make the row expandable. I wan the same functionality but not on click the Plus image, but on the name of the first column. i.e. from the above image when user clicks on "3m Co" from the company column. the Row should get expanded. i.e. what currently displayed in the image.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to stick with the rowexpander plugin - it's UI is much more user friendly than what you want to do.

The other way is to use rowbody and add custom functionality to collapse the rowbody with an itemclick listener - yeah good luck with that :)